# Video formats for html5 video players

Tags: php, javascript, html

I am creating a website, where users can upload their videos. I'm using the HTML5 video player from http://videojs.com/. How can I make HTML5 player play only MP4 on all browsers? If that is impossible, are there any ways to maybe convert MP4 to other formats?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Please read this blog post for the updated info:** http://blog.zencoder.com/2013/09/13/what-formats-do-i-need-for-html5-video/

**[Old Answer: Outdated]**

If you provide both `Ogg Theora` & `MP4` format then, you can cover almost all modern browsers ([ref](http://videojs.com/#compatibilitychart)). And, with some small effort you can find a lots of PHP implementation of the most popular & powerful open source video converter (`ffmpeg`). Or, you can make a small class for it too. Then use as -

```
<video id="my_video_1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls
  preload="auto" width="640" height="264" poster="my_video_poster.png"
  data-setup="{}">
  <source src="my_video.mp4" type='video/mp4'>
  <source src="my_video.ogv" type='video/ogg'>
</video>
```

PHP `ffmpeg` wrapper libs-

1. http://code.google.com/p/phpvideotoolkit/
2. http://ffmpeg-php.sourceforge.net/

Comment: This answer should probably be updated. Rather than mp4 and ogg, mp4 and webm are a better combo that should work w/ most modern browsers and provide better size vs quality efficiency. Even the example page cited (videojs) uses these 2 in its demos.

Comment: @BenA.Hilleli Thanks for the comment. The post is about 3 years old. I have added a blog post link so that people can get information about the latest formats.

Comment: And thanks for the update. It's definitely a 'good thing' as there still seems to be some confusion among many about html5 video

Comment: would it be practical to do the same for a messaging service ?